# CodeIgniter 2.2.0 form_helper giving errors

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am trying to use form_helper.php a helper class of codeigniter 2.2.0
and following is the error it's giving out when I try to do this :

**controller file**

```
 $this->load->helper('form');
```

**view file**

```
<?php 
  $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'admin-form');
  echo form_open($this, $attributes);
?>
```

**Error:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to
>   be string, object given
>
> Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 53
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message:  Object of class CI_Loader could not
>   be converted to string
>
> Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 61
>
> *Although it does print the  tag.*
>
> What I could be doing wrong here ?

Comment: form_open($this, $attributes) is your problem I think. The first parameter should be the controller method you want to link to.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
echo form_open($this, $attributes);
```

is in-correct. Correct it to:

```
echo form_open($YOUR_FORM_ACTION, $attributes);
```

[Reference](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Problem is occuring because, you are passing `$this`, an object instead of form action (string).

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$this` as the first argument as it is an internal CI object. Try:

```
echo form_open('controller/method', $attributes);
```